# difference between 'inter-city' and 'intercity'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences, hyphenation

in academic writing, I always note that 'inter-city' and 'intercity' also appear in a same paper in different context. I was wondering whether the two style have any differences? thanks very much

such as The resulting inter-city matrices, inter-city links ;worldwide inter-city relations

a valid pattern of intercity relations, an intercity corporate network

Comment: Hyphenation almost never actually matters. There is no real difference this time.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real difference between intercity and inter-city.

> Intercity or Inter-city means "between cities". It can refer to inter-city transportation by rail, bus, truck or airline. [Wikipedia Intercity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercity)